# Invalid number: not a valid number string error while CAST

Tags: select, casting, hana, varchar

I am working on scripter calculation view and one of my requirement is to select Quantity field (decimal) from a table and concatenate with character string.

```
   select cast(a.kwmeng as varchar) + ' * Textabc' as "QuantityFormula"
```

where Quantity formula is NVARCHAR type. When I activate the view i am receiving the following error.

> Could not derive table type for variable "VAR_OUT" (SQL error: invalid
>   number: not a valid number string

Can you guys provider pointers to fix this error.

Comment: There seems to be an implicit type conversion happening here. Please post the `out` data definition of the scripted calculation view.

Comment: Data definition:

vbeln nvarchar(10)
posnr nvarchar(10)
kwmeng decimal 13, 3
QuantityFormula nvarchar(60)

SQL 
select vbeln, posnr, kwmeng, 
cast(kwmeng as nvarchar) + '* Textabc' as "QuantityFormula"

Comment: We're missing something here. Please also check the activation log and the indexserver trace files for more detailed information. I'm rather sure that somewhere in the object definition a conversion TEXT -> NUMBER happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is with the `+` symbol. Try to use `||` instead. For your example it will be:

```
select cast(a.kwmeng as varchar) || ' * Textabc' as "QuantityFormula"
```

Comment: Can you check if this query works for you:
select cast(0.001 as varchar) || ' * Textabc' as "QuantityFormula" from dummy